# Detect .NET 4.5.2 in WiX as a Burn prerequisite

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn, .net-4.5.2

Starting from .NET 4.5.1, it seems we have to change the .NET detect condition for the [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) bootstrapper.

```
 <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                     Value="Release"
                     Variable="Netfx452FullVersion" />
 <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                     Value="Release"
                     Variable="Netfx452x64FullVersion"
                     Win64="yes" />
```

But the Release Registry value is a DWORD (379893 for .NET 4.5.2). Then how do we do integer comparison for DWORD? This will not work if I compare value of release with integer. Since value of release is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WiX 3.9 has support for .NET 4.5.2.  You can see the [wxs file on GitHub](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx452.wxs).

Burn is smarter than MSI.  It sees that the registry value is a DWORD and sets Release as a numeric variable.

Comment: is wix 3.9 stable enough to be used in production environment ?

Comment: @jero2rome Sorry I didn't respond earlier, I thought another RC was going to be announced.  It's pretty stable and should be released within a month.